# How to make a GET request from API that requires a Body and returns a boolean? Android/Kotlin/Retrofit

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, viewmodel

(For privacy purposes, I will be using very general terms)

Although I can make a GET request that takes in a body and returns a boolean successfully on Postman, as shown in this image
[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UImS1.png), I can't get it to work for my Android app.

I have an API interface with the code:

```
@GET("api/is_correct")
    suspend fun isCorrect(
       @Body email: Email
    ): Response<Boolean>
```

and a method in my view model as shown below

```
fun checkIfCorrect(input: String) {
        val email = Email(input)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val response = RetrofitInstance.api.isCorrect(email)
                Log.e(TAG, response.toString())
            } catch (e: Exception){
                Log.e(TAG, "error")
            }
        }
}
```

and this data class

```
data class Email (
    @SerializedName("email")
    val email: String
)
```

The log only prints out "error" when I call viewmodel.checkIfCorrect(...)

I've basically used the same process for all my other PUT, GET, and POST API calls. This is the only one that's causing trouble for me. I'm guessing it's because the response body for this particular api call isn't wrapped in { } and does not have a format like "result": true , the way other API responses do.

How can I fix this issue?

I've tried Response, Response, String, and Boolean as the return type for suspend fun isCorrect. I've also tried using Query("email") email: String and Path("email") email: String as the parameter for fun isCorrect even though my api endpoint does not require additional parameters in the URL, only the body.

Comment: Are you sure you want a GET with a body and not a POST? Also, have you tried printing the exception stacktrace to see what is the exact exception you get?

Comment: @gpunto Idk much about APIs. Someone else was responsible for making the endpoints and they defined this particular endpoint with a GET request, which works just fine on Postman. I get the error "Non-body HTTP method cannot contain Body.". What other Retrofit annotation would I use other than Body if the endpoint requires a body of { "email": "some email" }

Comment: tried using POST annotation and got the error "code=405, message=Method Not Allowed"

Comment: Hello! Add a breakpoint inside your catch block, so you can check the error message of the Exception, then edit please

Comment: When you catch an exception do not just print "error", you can print e.message

Comment: @ubewafersticks Before trying any workaround, I'd suggest asking the person responsible for the endpoint to support POST, which is the expected method for calls with a body at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If the api already exists there is not much you can do but try this as Retrofit may not support GET with body

```
        /**
         * import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
         * import okhttp3.Request
         * import okhttp3.RequestBody
         * import okhttp3.Response
         */
        val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .build()
        val mediaType: MediaType = MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json")
        val body: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{ \"message\":\"MESSAGE\"}")
        val request: Request = Request.Builder()
            .url("http://localhost:8080/sample/public")
            .method("GET", body)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .build()
        val response: Response = client.newCall(request).execute()
```